# Show a div for couple of seconds and then disappear automatically

Tags: jquery, hide, seconds

When a page loads, a `div` should appear for like 3 seconds and then automatically disappear. I'm having trouble with the code at the moment. I'm using this code below:

```
jQuery("#infor").delay(6000).fadeOut("slow");
```

My HTML is:

```
<div id="infor">
something
</div>
```

But it doesn't seem to be working. Does anyone have any idea why this code is not working?

Comment: Is working for me. But, 6000 stands for 6 seconds.

Comment: Seems to work just as youve posted it....http://jsfiddle.net/CZ8dJ/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is your code within a `document.ready` block?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#infor").delay(3000).fadeOut("slow");
});
```

It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/YdU4z/

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax appears to be correct (*however if you wanted the delay to be for about 3 seconds, you should change the value inside the delay to 3000*).

Do you have this code being wrapped within a document-ready block as seen below?

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
     //Short-hand for $(document).ready()
     $(function(){
         //Delay for ~3 seconds and then fade out
         $("#infor").delay(3000).fadeOut("slow");
     });
 </script>
```

**[Working Example](http://jsbin.com/ArAguda/1/edit)**

I would try using the Developer Tools (F12) within your browser to see if any errors are being thrown (*within the Console*) and also ensure that the version of jQuery you are using supports the functions being called as well.